# Cannot set property 'backgroundSize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change size of background-image in JavaScript but it does not work out. Console.log says "Cannot set property 'backgroundSize' of undefined". My code is

```
document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-8").style.backgroundSize = "100px";
```

[My project in codepen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/xOPyZR)

Please can anyone explain me what is a trick here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-8")[0].style.backgroundSize = "100px";
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object instead of just one object. If you want to change the `backgroundSize` of all elements of that class, you can use

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-8");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.backgroundSize = "100px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful!